# Matlab change a single point in a plot without replotting

Tags: matlab, plot, octave

So I have a plot of N points in the 2D plane (N can be very large). I am writing a script that is to show the workings of an algorithm. So I have for loops. At each step in the for loop I'd like to change the color of the current point (actually probably make a stem plot with just this point).

However, at the end of the step I'd like to remove the coloring of the current point so that I can color the next one. Currently I have to redraw the whole plot (incl. the 2D points). I'm not sure whether Matlab detects such things in the plotting commands but is there a way to do this without redrawing the whole plot?

For example:

```
plot(x,y, '*');


for j = 1:N-1
    for i = j:N
        hold on;
        %Do stuff

        plot(x,y, '*');
        hold on;
        stem(x(1), y(1), 'g*');
    end

end
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A quick example:

```
%# plot some data
x = 1:100;
y = cumsum(rand(size(x))-0.5);
plot(x,y,'*-')

%# animate by going through each point
hold on
h = stem(x(1),y(1),'g');
hold off
for i=1:numel(x)
    %# update the stem x/y data
    set(h, 'XData',x(i), 'YData',y(i));

    %# slow down a bit, drawnow was too fast!
    pause(.1)
end
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Nice example.  As promised, +1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at the documentation of [handle graphics objects](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/learn_matlab/f3-15974.html).

I'd recommend plotting the whole set of points as one object.  Then, for each iteration, plot the point of interest.  Save a handle to it (as in, `h = plot(...);`).  When you're ready for the next iteration, `delete` the object using that handle (`delete(h)`), and create the next one in the same manner.

```
%# outside the for loop (do this once)
plot(x,y,'*');

for...
    h = stem(x(i),y(i),'g*');
    ...
    %# next iteration... i has been incremented
    delete(h);
    h = stem(x(i),y(i),'g*');
end
```

Comment: or call `stem` once, and update its `XData` and `YData` properties each iteration. Also you might want to put a `drawnow` or `pause(..)` inside the loop to flush the UI queue

Comment: @Amro agreed. There are many ways to do it; either generically "get rid of one thing and put in another", or "update the object that is already there" - I wasn't in the mood for a full tutorial. If you want to add those options in an answer, you'll get a +1 from me.  I also implicitly figured the `pause` was inside the `do stuff` section, but if not, it is a good idea.